# php 8 days created for week

Tags: php, date

I have the following code that creates a list of dates between a range. If I supply a day of the week it will get all dates for thoes dates in the range. If I dont it will get all days.

My problem is that from the 24th of october to the 29th it returns an extra day. I noticed the before when I added the extra code to get the dates of a day of the week.

The problem line I think is array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo,$dateOfWeek=null) {
  // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
  // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

  // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
  // that in the main script

  $aryRange=array();

  $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
  $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

  if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) {

    if(!isset($dateOfWeek)) {   
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry

        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {
          $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
          array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    } else {

        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {
          if(date('w',$iDateFrom)==$dateOfWeek)
              array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
              $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
        }       
    }
  }

  if(count($aryRange)<1){
    return false;
  } else{
    return $aryRange;
  }

}
```

Comment: Look into using the DateTime class. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use the strtotime() function?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$iDateFrom = strtotime("+1 day", $iDateFrom); // add 1 day
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for the `daylight saving time`.

-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: Thanks for that, that was exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding 24 hours each time. That's not quite the same thing as adding a day. I strongly suspect that you're operating in a time zone where the clock goes back on October 23rd or October 30th, and this is messing up your calculations.

It's not entirely clear to me what the best solution is for you here, but hopefully explaining what is going on will be a good start...

Answer (score 1):

The quick & dirty solution is to add a couple of hours of time difference to the dates you're comparing. This way daylight saving time doesn't affect the calculations enough to throw them off.

```
$iDateFrom=mktime(12,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
$iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));
```

The better solution is to use actual date manipulating functions instead of manually adding 24 hours.